# How can I say "Vous nous appelez quand?" with an inverted structure?

Tags: questions, inversion

I keep getting the inverted form, used in questioning, mixed up.

I realize that to ask a question, one could just use "est-ce que" or alternatively to change one's tone of voice, like asking "Vous nous appelez?" which means, will you call us?

But what if I wanted to ask the question using the inversion? Does "Vous nous appelez" become:

Appelez-vous nous? or Appelez-nous vous?

Or, to use a slightly different question, with "quand" at the end (i.e. Vous nous appelez quand?), does it become:

Quand appelez-vous nous? or Quand appelez-nous vous?

Is there a logical explanation about the placement of these words that I can apply so I can reason about it instead of just memorizing them?

Answer (score 8):

> Vous nous appelez. > Nous appelez-vous ?

> Vous nous appelez demain. > Quand nous appelez-vous ?

The basic rule: Invert the subject and the verb.

But when you do so, if there's an object pronoun, keep it with the verb.

Simple examples:

> Tu lis. > Lis-tu ?

> Tu le lis. > Le lis-tu ?

More complex:

> Tu m'envoies un paquet demain. > Quand m'envoies-tu un paquet ?

> Tu me l'envoies demain. > Quand me l'envoies-tu ?

Comment: I'll add "Quand est-ce que vous nous appelez ?" which sound more usual than "Quand vous appelez-nous ?"

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say it's better to say the first than the second question, but where did the second question (Quand vous appelez-nous) come from? Luke wrote "Quand nous appelez-vous ?" which is different. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Velo-p I think XouDo might be comparing the other two question types, adding est-ce que and pure intonation, but accidentally added a hyphen to the latter. (With the hyphen, *Quand vous appelez-nous* would be wrong, not just unnatural.) Either that or he does mean to compare est-ce que and inversion but misread me :)

Comment: I guess XouDo wanted to write *Quand nous appelez-vous?* In real life, inversion is indeed avoided as much as possible. You would hear more *Quand est-ce que vous nous appelez ?* *Vous nous appelez quand ?* or even *C'est quand que vous nous appelez ?*,  colloquial but very common.

Comment: @jlliagre Good inventory. (I only touched on the formation of the structure in my answer, since the question seemed to be about grammar rather than usage.)

Comment: Right. My impression is non native learners sometimes tend to overuse inversion compared to native.

Comment: @jlliagre Yeah, for me, coming from English, I think inversion feels more natural since English usually uses inversion via helper verbs, i.e. *"When **are** you calling us?"* vs *"You're calling us when?"* or *"When is it that you're calling us?"*

Comment: "C'est quand que vous nous appelez ?, colloquial but very common." @jlliagre Oui et tac.  Même dans les méthodes dites prescriptives de FLES on introduit et enseigne "c'est quand ton anniversaire ?" au lieu de "Quand est-ce ton anniversaire ?" Petit à petit pas à pas !

Comment: @Livresque Mais je soupçonne qu'on n'y enseigne pas encore ***C'est quand que c'est ton anniversaire !*** ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Non ça c'est le chapitre bcp plus tard ***C'est con que c'est ton anniversaire, c'est qui qui a dit que c'est quand c'que c'est ta fête ?"***

Comment: @livresque ***Cékikadiksékanksététafèt ?*** ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no logical explanation, merely an established usage that you have to remember, just as in English when you have to place the auxiliary "do" before the subject ("When do you call them? - When does the mailman call them?").

In French, the complement precedes the verb if it is a pronoun, it follows the verb otherwise .

[place du complément](https://parlez-vous-french.com/la-place-des-pronoms-complements/)

*rather formal, yet not too formal for current conversation*

- Quand **nous** appelez-vous ? - **Nous** appelez-vous sur notre téléphone fixe ? - **Nous** appelez-vous ?
- Appelez-vous **vos voisins** sur leur téléphone fixe ?
- Quand **l**'appelez-vous ? - Quand **les** appelez-vous ?
- Quand appelez-vous **notre service après-vente** ?
- Quand appellerez-vous **le mécanicien** ? - Quand **l**'appellerez-vous ?

*usual: with "est-ce que", the subject is placed as in the affirmative sentence, but the rule for the complement is the same.*

- Quand *est-ce que VOUS* **nous** appelez ? - *Est-ce que VOUS* **nous** appelez sur notre téléphone fixe ? - *Est-ce que VOUS* **nous** appelez ?
- *Est-ce que VOUS* appelez **vos voisins** sur leur téléphone fixe ?
- Quand *est-ce que VOUS* **l**'appelez ? - Quand *est-ce que VOUS* **les** appelez ?
- Quand *est-ce que VOUS* appelez **notre service après-vente** ?
- Quand *est-ce que VOUS* appellerez **le mécanicien** ? - Quand *est-ce que VOUS* **l**'appellerez ?

---

<s>Appelez-vous nous? or Appelez-nous vous?

Quand appelez-vous nous? or Quand appelez-nous vous?</s>